# Möbius transformation of two discs

Tags: complex-analysis

*Let $T(z) = \frac{z-i}{z+i}$ be a given Möbiustransformation. Find the image under the mapping of $T$ over $G = \{z : |z|<1 \} \cap \{z : |z-1|<1 \}$*

**Attempted solution**

Let's call $C_1 = \{z : |z| <1 \}$ and $C_2 = \{z : |z-1| <1 \}$. When we map $C_1$ under $T$ we see that the point $i$ which is on the circle gets mapped to $T(i) = 0$ and so we expect $-i$ to get mapped onto a straight line that passes through $0$. So I should expect it to be either the real or the imaginary axis. We see that it must be the imaginary axis because $T(1) = -i$ which is on the imaginary. But since we are mapping a disc containing origin we expect a halfplane. Notice $T(0) = -1$ so we have mapped the left halfplane.

**The problem**

The problem is that I don't know how to find the image which $C_2$ gets mapped to. Any hints?